# Capacitor of choice for low noise applications

Tags: capacitor, analog, noise, oscillator, stability

I saw in a schematic a while back that a polypropylene capacitor was used to generate a stable sine wave in an oscillator circuit. I suppose this gave a better 'frequency reference' for the oscillator.

Are some capacitor types better for lower noise applications?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HighK ceramics like X7R, Z5U etc have huge variation of capacitance versus voltage. Using them in filters or any kind of coupling application guarantees humongous distortion. They are piezoelectric: they are both good loudspeakers and microphones. Decoupling a high impedance node with them results in a nice vibration detector. Tolerance on values are not huge, rather they are hyuuuge: expect +20/-50% depending on DC bias. Also, they drift a lot with temperature.

They are truly excellent for power supply decoupling, though, because they are small, have lots of capacitance per volume, low inductance, and are cheap. For decoupling, who cares if it's 1µF +/- 50%?

Now, for filtering applications, or when you run a signal through a cap as in your oscillator application, you want...

- A known precise value
- Low temperature drift
- No capacitance variation with voltage
- Low sensitivity to vibration

Dielectric absorption and leakage will not matter for your oscillator, but they will for other applications.

Film caps and NP0 ceramic caps are excellent on this, although:

- large thru-hole film caps tend to be microphonic
- polyester has worse dC/dV than the other films and NP0

Your first choice should be NP0 ceramics if they are available in the value you need. They are small and cheap, and almost perfect.

NP0 ceramics and High-K ceramics like X7R/Z5U are completely different materials. High-K capacitance varies with DC bias, NP0 does not.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen designs with 0.1% resistors and low tolerance caps for filters. Another thing I do is use XY caps where things need to be matched.

Answer (score 3):

Film capacitor are widely used in applications that require high stability of the capacitance value. In audio, they're used for the signal path, whereas electrolytic or ceramic are used for bypassing.

Film capacitor lack the parasitic piezoelectric effect present in ceramics, and they also are very stable with respect to its bias voltage. In ceramics it's the other way round: capacitance can change up to -90% with bias voltage, introducing enormous nonlinearities if used in the signal path.

Comment: Say rather that high K ceramics have the horrible performance, C0G is often superior to film. Also remember that ONLY **filter** caps should have meaningful signal voltage present across them, coupling caps should be large enough to ensure that the signal develops negligible voltage across the cap, so more or less anything works here, and to some extent a high value electrolytic trumps a too low value film if the film puts the high pass pole too close to the audio band or is microphonic (Large thru hole films sometimes suffer from this).

Comment: NP0/C0G ceramic capacitors are not superior to film in certain applications, typically, where precise timing and/or very low Dielectric Absorption is needed. The canonical example is instrumentation circuits (active or passive integrators). For very low DA you will most probably have to choose film capacitors (for instance, PPS), mica and/or Silicon.

Comment: @DanMills Coupling caps may have small signal voltages across them, but they could have large DC voltage biases across them - after all, that's the point of the coupling, to allow signals to be converted from one DC bias to another DC bias. With this in mind, capacitor selection is still important, and one must be mindful of capacitance degradation due to the bias voltage when using ceramic caps for this purpose (although you are correct that they shouldn't be making much noise because the *signal* voltage should be low)

Comment: @BeB00 Oh indeed you got to pick the part for the job, and high K ceramics, particularly in small packages are a bit notorious for voltage coefficient. My point was more that in terms of minimising distortion in a coupling cap, more or less anything works as long as it is big enough. There is however more to selecting the correct part then just considerations of distortion! There is a reason the many different types of cap exist, and usually picking the right one is a tradeoff and NONE of the things are really ideal.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this in the LT6657 datasheet:

> For very low noise applications, film capacitors should be considered
>   for their lack of piezoelectric effects. Film capacitors such as
>   polyester, polycarbonate and polypropylene have good temperature
>   stability. Additional care must be taken as polypropylene have an
>   upper limit of 85°C to 105°C. Above these temperatures the working
>   voltage often needs to be derated per manufacturer specifications.
>   Another type of film capacitor is polyphenylene sulfide (PPS). These
>   capacitors work over a wide temperature range, are stable and have
>   large capacitance values beyond 1μF

And [from a manufacturer](http://www.exxelia.com/all-products/capacitors/films/polypropylene-capacitors/)

> Polypropylene is generally selected for its excellent dielectric
>   characteristics (losses, absorption, dielectric strength, insulation
>   resistance:
>
> - very low Tgd and dielectric loss,
> - low dielectric absorption,
> - excellent dielectric strength,
> - high insulation resistance,
> - temperature- and frequency-stable characteristics,
> - excellent self-healing properties for metallized Polypropylene,
> - etc.

Answer (score 2):

We use a lot of C0G (NP0) dielectric ceramic capacitors. Our typically application where use is for very narrow band and low noise filtering and single stage CE amplifier. Input signals are typically below 1mv at 1MHz

**Do keep what Enric said in mind.** Especially with DC bias. That will quickly kill your effective capacitance of which ever part you choose. This can be offset by choose a larger value capacitance and voltage rating part which potentially means more cost and larger footprint.